# .bind() not working for shift-key binds?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As you can tell this is my calculator program. I wanted the user to be able to use it not only by clicking the buttons with the mouse, but to also be able to use the keyboard. So I used .bind() and all of them work fine, except for the 5 binds that use the shift key, only the first two(shift-= and shift-8) work, and I do not see a reason why the other three(shift-6, shift-5 and shift-1) don't work. Every time I click Shift-1 or SHift-5 or Shift-6 it literally does nothing.

btw here are is the section of the code containing the binds if u couldn't find it above:

```
# ---------------Key Bindings---------------

        root.bind('<Delete>', self.button_clear_press)

        root.bind('<Escape>', self.button_off_press)

        root.bind('`', self.chargeInvert)

        root.bind('=', self.equals)

        root.bind('.', self.decimal)

        root.bind('9', lambda x: self.numButton_press('9'))

        root.bind('8', lambda x: self.numButton_press('8'))

        root.bind('7', lambda x: self.numButton_press('7'))

        root.bind('6', lambda x: self.numButton_press('6'))

        root.bind('5', lambda x: self.numButton_press('5'))

        root.bind('4', lambda x: self.numButton_press('4'))

        root.bind('3', lambda x: self.numButton_press('3'))

        root.bind('2', lambda x: self.numButton_press('2'))

        root.bind('1', lambda x: self.numButton_press('1'))

        root.bind('0', lambda x: self.numButton_press('0'))

        root.bind('+', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('+'))

        root.bind('<Shift-=>', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('+'))

        root.bind('-', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('-'))

        root.bind('*', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('×'))

        root.bind('<Shift-8>', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('×'))

        root.bind('/', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('÷'))

        root.bind('<Shift-6>', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('^'))

        root.bind('<Shift-5>', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('%'))

        root.bind('<Shift-1>', lambda x: self.mathButton_press('!'))
```

Comment: You posted way too much code. If the problem is with a binding on a shifted key, you don't need the bindings for all the other keys. You also don't need much more code than one or two widgets. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you explain further as to what you mean by you dont need for all the other keys. you see im still a begginner in python so if theres another way to bind these keys then please explain.

Comment: Also Thank you for taking the time to comment and help me out

Comment: Try looking at [this.](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/467452/updated-tiny-tkinter-calculator-python) The `create_widgets` function in the code there has a great example.

Comment: I meant thet you don't need all the bindings _for the purposes of this question_

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help, I looked into it and im going to try it right now

Comment: `<1>` means `mouse left button` so `<Shift-1>` means `Shift + mouse left button`

Comment: so how would i make it so that shift plus the NUmber 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<1>` means `mouse left button` so `<Shift-1>` means `Shift + mouse left button`

Some keys have special names - `keysym` - which you have to use in you code.

ie.

- `Shift + 1` is `<exclam>`
- `Shift + Keypad 1` is `<KP_End>` (but it depends on `Num Lock`)

You can use this code to see `keysym` when you will press keys

```
import tkinter as tk

def test(event):
    print('keysym:', event.keysym)

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<Key>', test)

root.mainloop()
```

You can find some names on pages like [Tcl/Tk - keysym](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm) or [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python: 54.5. Key names](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/key-names.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, you have no idea how much I appreciate this.