# How to make two presses make the same output in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I want to make a Tkinter program which binds two inputs to one output i tried this:

```
def hh(event):
      print('hello')
root.bind(<Returna>, hh)
```

and

```
def hh(event):
    print('hello')
root.bind('<Return, KeyPress-a>')
```

But it did not work as expected.
Can someone tell me how I can make `<Shift>` and `<KeyPress-a>` together to trigger `hh()`?
Thanks!

First Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tktest.py", line 19, in <module>
    root.bind('<Returna>', hh)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/`__init__.`py", line 1251, in bind
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/`__init__`.py", line 1206, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Returna"
```

Second error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "tktest.py", line 19, in <module>  
    root.bind('<Return, KeyPress-a>', hh)  
  File  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1251, in bind  
    return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)  
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1206, in _bind  
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))  
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Return,"
```

Comment: did you get error message ? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should use string `"<Return>a"` and add function name `root.bind("<Return>a", hh)` but it will run `hh()` when you press `Enter` and later `a`. If you want run when you press `Enter` OR `a` then you have to do two binds `root.bind("<Return>", hh)` and `root.bind("a", hh)`

Comment: What is `<Returna>` supposed to represent? Is it the return key, followed by a lowercase `a` key?

Comment: yes, that's what `'<Returna>'` was supposed to be

Comment: in new description you write `<Shift> and <KeyPress-a>` but in code all time you  use `<Return>`, not `<Shift>` ? So which key you need ? `<Return>` or `<Shift>` ?

Comment: If you want to press `Shift` and `a` then use `A` - `bind('A', hh)`

Comment: in second error you try `Return` and `,` but maybe you mean `Shift` and `,` which has name `less` - `bind("<less>", hh)`.

Comment: Using code from [.bind() not working for shift-key binds?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40951463/1832058) you can display `keysym` for pressed key(s) which you can use with `bind()`. There is also link to list with keysym names because some combinations has special name.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use string `'<Return>a'` and add function's name

```
root.bind('<Return>a', hh)
```

but it will run `hh()` when you press `a` directly after `Enter`

---

```
import tkinter as tk

def hh(event):
      print('hello')

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>a', hh)
root.mainloop()
```

---

If you want to run `hh()` when you press `Enter` OR `a` then you need two binds

```
root.bind('<Return>', hh)
root.bind('a', hh)
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

def hh(event):
      print('hello')

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Return>', hh)
root.bind('a', hh)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

In edited question I see `<Shift>` so maybe it has to be `Shift + a`?  It would need `A`

```
root.bind('A', hh) # Shift + a
```

In second error I see `Return,` but maybe it has to be `Shift + ,` which has special name `<less>`

```
root.bind('<less>', hh) # Shift + ,
```

In asnwer to [.bind() not working for shift-key binds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949940/bind-not-working-for-shift-key-binds/40951463#40951463) I shown code which display `keysym` for pressed key and which you can use in `bind()`

```
import tkinter as tk

def test(event):
    print('keysym:', event.keysym)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Key>', test)
root.mainloop()
```

Some names you can find in documentation [Tcl/Tk - keysym](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/keysyms.htm)

But there is no special `keysym` for `Return + a` or `Return + ,` because it is unusual combination and it may need to keep pressed `Return`/`Enter` and then press `a` or `,`. Or press `Return`, release `Return`, and press `a` or `,`

Comment: it did not give me an error message but it did not give an output either when i did `'<Return>a'`. I don't know if i'm in a older version of python or something but it did not work.